# I was trying to make a 2D array of a class object, but I keep getting an error. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, class, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I continue getting a null pointer exception on a 2D array of class TicTacToe which holds a 2D array itself.

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TicTacToe[][] ultGame = new TicTacToe[3][3];
        for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {
                ultGame[a][b].printBoard();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is my main method, which makes a 2D array of and calls upon the TicTacToe class(see below). The Null Pointer Exception happens in the nested for loop, as I am calling ultGame[a][b]

```
class TicTacToe
{
    private String[][] board = {{"-","-","-"},{"-","-","-"},{"-","-","-"}};
    public TicTacToe ()
    {
    }
    public void printBoard()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[a][b] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody could help me either figure out how to fix this or help to do the same thing in a different way, then please let me know.

I tried 3 things:

1. I have tried calling a new TicTacToe object and assigning it to a variable game.
   `TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();`
   Then, I made the 2D array with this object instead.
   `game[][] ultGame = new game[3][3]`
   This resulted in an error message where "game" was not recognized as declared.
2. I have tried go through each individual index rather than putting it in a nested for loop to find where the problem is. All of them are null.
3. The last thing I tried was set up an if statement that would register if it was null and then try to assign it a new intialized TicTacToe to try and see if that would make it not null, but that did not work.

```
if(ultGame[a][b].equals(null))
{
    ultGame[a][b] = new TicTacToe();
}
```

Comment: `TicTacToe[][] ultGame = new TicTacToe[3][3];` is making an 3x3 array which CAN hold instances of `TicTacToe`, but at the time of creation, contains nothing (each element is `null`), not having said that, I don't understand why you're creating a `3x3` array of `TicTacToe` when it contains a `3x3` board

Comment: If you really want to use `TicTacToe[][] ultGame = new TicTacToe[3][3];`, then you would need to use a compound loop to create an instance of `TicTacToe` for each element. Remember `new TicTacToe[3][3]` is just creating the array, not the instances of the object which the array might hold

Comment: @MadProgrammer The code is to make a game of Ultimate Tic Tac Toe game and I needed both the ultimate board and the smaller boards to have their own methods. I will be trying out the loop to initialize everything in ultGame.